# function for multiplication of two 2d-array row by row

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication, multiplication, numpy-ndarray

I need a simple and fast function to multiply each row of numpy array 'a' to array 'b'
a , b have same 2d dimention
like the result of this is example(c):
but I want a numpy function insted of this loop

```
a=np.arange(6).reshape(3,2)
b=np.arange(6,12).reshape(3,2)
c=np.array([[a[i,:]@b[i,:]]for i in range(a.shape[0])])
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your arrays with your code, so I assumed you meant `a=np.arange(6).reshape(3,2)` and `b=np.arange(7,13).reshape(3,2)`

Comment: You're right. then I edited the Q

Comment: To use `@` you have to tweak the dimensions a bit: `(a[:,None,:]@b[:,:,None])[:,0,:]`.  Because at it's core `@` is designed to work with `n-2d` arrays.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way would be to write it yourself with vectorized `numpy` methods:

```
np.sum(a*b,axis=1,keepdims=True)

array([[  8],
       [ 48],
       [104]])
```

Comment: that works fine. can anybody find another way or with np.einsum solution

Comment: As suggested in the duplicate question: `np.einsum('ij,ij->i',a,b)`